# How to add a package to nuget/nupack?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget, nuget-package

How can I have a package added to the list of available package of nuget/nupack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the instructions here: http://nupackpackages.codeplex.com/

Basically, fork that project, then use use hg (Mercurial) version control to get the project source to your machine, add your package to the packages directory, commit your change, push it up to your fork, then send a pull request.